# Scrape the data and store to dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, selenium-chromedriver

I was trying to scrape the data from the website link and when we click on the "Sterne Anzeigen" button at the bottom of the review we find the sub ratings and wanted to scrape that rating and store it in the CSV file. I was able to perform the actions like clicking on the button for each review and write code to extract the sub ratings as below

```
articles=browser.find_elements_by_class_name("index__reviewBlock__27gnB")

data=[]

for article in articles:

try:
   element2 = article.find_elements_by_tag_name('button')
except EX.NoSuchElementException:
   pass

for element in element2:
   ActionChains(browser).click(element).perform()

row={}  

Stars=article.find_elements_by_class_name("index__factor__3Z15R")


for item in Stars:
  key = item.find_element_by_class_name("index__title__W4hOp").text
  value = item.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='index__stars__2ads4 index__medium__1wpWb 
   index__stars__3lgvx']").get_attribute("data-score")
  row[key]=value

data.append(row)
```

Can anyone help me to get the exact ratings since using this code I'm getting all the rating value "5"?

Thanks in advance

Comment: is It possible for you to share either Page link or Page HTML source code ?

Comment: Hi @rahulrai Sure, https://www.kununu.com/de/volkswagen/kommentare

Comment: Ufff!!!! Let me tell you it took me 2 hours to first debug your code and then another hour to get desired result. Issue with your code is in line **key = item.find_element_by_class_name("index__title__W4hOp").text and 
  value = item.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='index__stars__2ads4 index__medium__1wpWb**. As with above it is identifying !249 elements and not only the review title and rating for a particular review. Also when you are using WebElement.find_element_by_xpath(xpath), you should use one . before // in your xpath.

Comment: Now as for first review all titles rating is 5 as a result it was always printing 5 for all reviews. Please see Answer section fora complete solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is to only get value of index title and rating belongs to each Review. See below should work:

**Edit :** It will capture rating and category for all reviews

```
reviews = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='index__reviewBlock__27gnB']")

data=[]
for rev in reviews:

    row = {}
    rev_Heading = rev.find_element_by_xpath(".//h3").text
    try:
        btn = rev.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[text()='Sterne anzeigen' or text()='Alle anzeigen']") # To click only button with text Sterne anzeigen
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", btn)
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", btn)
        time.sleep(1)

        index_titles_xpath = "//div[h3[text()='" + rev_Heading + "']]//following-sibling::div//div[@class='index__block__36tsj index__scoreBlock__1t7Du']//preceding-sibling::h4"
        score_blocks_xpath = "//div[h3[text()='" + rev_Heading + "']]//following-sibling::div//div[@class='index__block__36tsj index__scoreBlock__1t7Du']/span"
        index_titles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(index_titles_xpath)
        score_blocks = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(score_blocks_xpath)

        for key, value in zip(index_titles, score_blocks):
            row[key.text]  = value.get_attribute("data-score")
        data.append(row)
        btnclose = rev.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[text()='Sterne ausblenden' or text()='Weniger anzeigen']")  #  to click only button with text Sterne ausblenden
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", btnclose)
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", btnclose)
        time.sleep(1)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        index_titles_xpath = "//div[h3[text()='"+rev_Heading+"']]//following-sibling::div//div[@class='index__block__36tsj index__scoreBlock__1t7Du']//preceding-sibling::h4"
        score_blocks_xpath = "//div[h3[text()='"+rev_Heading+"']]//following-sibling::div//div[@class='index__block__36tsj index__scoreBlock__1t7Du']//span"
        index_titles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(index_titles_xpath)
        score_blocks = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(score_blocks_xpath)
        for key, value in zip(index_titles, score_blocks):
            row[key.text] = value.get_attribute("data-score")
        data.append(row)
for d in data:
    print(d)
```

**Out Put:** As there are 10 reviews on your page , below output we would get:

[image]

Comment: Hi @rahul rai,Thanks for your effort in this.Clicking on the 'Sterne Anzeigen' is only for the reference I want the data extraction to be done for all the reviews present in the site.So It would be great if you make the changes on the code for the complete data scraping.

Comment: @Barbie143 Sure I will have a look at  it. Also if answer helps you solve your original doubt / issue, please accept it. Cheers !!!

Comment: Sure I'll definitely do that

Comment: And adding to this if the button is not available then it is not extracting the star ratings could you please check that too

Comment: That because I assume you only want rating if Sterne Anzeigen button is present. So your requirement is you want overall rating for all reviews, As well as rating for all 13 contributing indexes ? Is it so ?

Comment: I just wanted to explain using the scenario and in many reviews we will find that button so I gave a scenario. I won't think it would take time to figure it out for you so please help me in this.Thanks in advance

Comment: Please help me in this I'll definitely accept it as an answer

Comment: Hey @Barbie143 Please see the updated solution, now script will store index title and corresponding rating for all reviews. Irrespective of button **Sterne anzeigen** is present or button **Alle anzeigen** is present or no button is present.